# Request header not set as expected when using 'no-cors' mode with fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fiddler, fetch-api

I have a fetch where the request types seems to be changing which is messing up my post.  I submit my basic form (one field only).  Here is the fetch.

```
      handleSubmit(event, data) {
    //alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("SUBMIT STATE::", this.state.value);
    return (
        fetch("//localhost:5000/api/values/dui/", {
            method: "post",
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',                  
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.value,
            })
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                this.setState({
                    value: 'no greeting - status > 400'
                });
                throw new Error('no greeting - throw');
            }
            return response.text()
        }).then(data => {
            var myData = JSON.parse(data);
            this.setState({
                greeting: myData.name,
                path: myData.link
            });
        }).catch(() => {
            this.setState({
                value: 'no greeting - cb catch'
            })
        })
    );


}
```

But when I look at this in fiddler content-type is now 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'.  Here is the raw Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/values/dui/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
accept: application/json
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
   Referer: http://localhost:3000/
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

```
{"name":"molly"}
```

In DOM Inspector I just see:

POST http://localhost:5000/api/values/dui/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

I also find it strange that 'accept' is lower case as well as 'content-type'.  Any reason why this is happening.  I haven't found anything specific in my searches yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `no-cors` mode is set for a request, browsers won’t allow you to set any request headers other than [CORS-safelisted request-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header). See [the spec requirements about adding headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-headers-append):

> To append a name/value (*name*/*value*) pair to a `Headers` object (*headers*), run these steps:
>
> 5. Otherwise, if *guard* is "`request-no-cors`" and *name*/*value* is not a [CORS-safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), return.

In that algorithm, `return` equates to “return without adding that header to the Headers object”.

And the reason it’s instead getting set to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` is because [the algorithm for the request constructor](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request) calls into an [*extract a body* algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract) which includes this step:

> Switch on *object*’s type:
>
> ↪ **USVString**
>
> - Set `Content-Type` to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what resolved this issue, I switched 'no-cors' to 'cors'.  Frankly I thought I had flipped flopped these before because of cross origin issues I was having between my local development workstation and the server I was deploying to but needless to say, when I set this back to mode: 'cors', it all worked again.  Both local workstation and server.  Why that changes the actual request header, Im not sure.  If anyone has answers for that I'll gladly upvote.

Thanks.