# NextJs - Use fetch() to make api call with POST method - always ERR_ABORTED 400

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

when I try to make api call with **fetch() method and request type is POST**, then I receive error in console: "**POST ... ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad request)**"

btw. I have used 'no-cors' mode because api url is on different domain, I know that this is not best approach. For now I just want to make it to work and later I will deal with CORS issue that I have when mode is not set to 'no-cors'.

```
    const res = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        sku: sku
    }),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: "no-cors"
});
```

What can be the cause why fetch() method always returns error, maybe something with the syntax? **Both "sku" and "jwtToken" variables are set.**

I tried it with postman and everything works fine, but when I try to make that api call inside nextjs then its not working.

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42377983/441757. When you use no-cors mode, the browser won’t actually send any request headers you’re trying to add in your frontend JavaScript code. That’s one reason among the many other reasons why code should essentially never, ever use no-cors mode — not even for testing. no-cors mode is basically never going to cause what anyone would hope it might.